# Android with Volley: sending objects via POST parameters

Tags: android, android-volley, stripe-payments

I'm using volley to send Stripe payments data to my server.

This is the code in Stripe documentation.

```
final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
// Code from Stripe.com documentation..
Card card = new Card("4242424242424242", "12", "2014", "123");

Stripe stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_api_key");
stripe.createToken(
  card,
  new TokenCallback() {
      public void onSuccess(Token token) {
          // Send token to your server via POST request
          params.put("stripeToken", token);
      }
      public void onError(Exception error) {
          // Show localized error message
          Toast.makeText(getContext(),
            error.getLocalizedString(getContext()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
          ).show();
      }
  }
```

However, when using Volley to send a POST request to my server, I override the `getParams()` method but I'm not able to send the token because the map object should be `Map<String, String>` and not `Map<String, Object>`

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        // Success
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        // Error
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                queue.add(request);
```

Is there a way to pass the token object to the server?

Comment: Perhaps the token should be sent in the headers?

Comment: @BNK What are the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't send the entire Token [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) here and just send the token id `tok_XXX` instead.

```
final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
// Code from Stripe.com documentation..
Card card = new Card("4242424242424242", "12", "2014", "123");

Stripe stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_api_key");
stripe.createToken(
  card,
  new TokenCallback() {
      public void onSuccess(Token token) {
          // Send token to your server via POST request
          params.put("stripeToken", token.getId());
      }
      public void onError(Exception error) {
          // Show localized error message
          Toast.makeText(getContext(),
            error.getLocalizedString(getContext()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
          ).show();
      }
  }
```

You can then use that token server-side or retrieve all the information via the [Retrieve Token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_token) API.